# github - adding more information about a file in commit

Tags: github, github-api

In github, after a commit is made, I want to go through the set of files in the commit and compute/assign some scores and additional meta data to each file which will be useful to reviewers of the file. I want this meta data to show up next to the file.

Is there a way to do it directly or is there a way to write some a plug in that does this which integrates into github?

Comment: What kind of information do you want to add?

Comment: Let's say, I have a bug score for each file. I want to show it in the UI of github so that my reviewers would know whether to be extra careful when reviewing a particular file if the bug score is high. It gives the picture?

Comment: How about writing this information in the file header as a comment? The reviewers will be able to identify the change.